# .NET MVC (Razor) Authentication with Keycloak

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, openid-connect, keycloak

we are implementing a new authorization mechanism into our existing .NET Application based on Razor Framework. As Identity Provider we want to use [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/), which a colleague recommended us.

We followed the instructions from this Tutorial:
[Keycloak Owin ASP.NET MVC Tutorial](https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/wiki/ASP.NET-MVC-Tutorial)

We have installed Keycloak and customized the Startup.cs to prepare the app for KeycloakAuthentication:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {    
    const string persistentAuthType = "keycloak_cookies";
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
                AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType
    });

    app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions {
        Realm = "master",
        ClientId = "eservice",
        ClientSecret = "<<client-Secret>>",
        VirtualDirectory = "",
        KeycloakUrl = "<Keycloak URL>>",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
        AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
        UseRemoteTokenValidation = true,
        DisableAudienceValidation = true, 
        DisableIssuerValidation = true
    });
 }
```

Keycloak configuration:
[image: Keycloak configuration]

When starting the application we get the typical Keycloak login screen. But after logging in, we get the following error message:

> [SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid': '4385f0fb-2c47-4787-aece-31937e230fd9', token: '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"4385f0fb-2c47-4787-aece-31937e230fd9"}.{"jti":"619b6b23-aa0f-40d3-9603-94445db7c763","exp":1554799904,"nbf":0,"iat":1554798104,"iss":"https://...

It seems like Keycloak uses the HS256 algorithm, but we have definitely set up RS256 for signing the JWT.

Comment: I think the problem comes from where you generate the token, because you set up your server with `RSA` but you generate a `JWT` with `HS256` algorithm, you should check where you generate the `JWT` the issue might come from that

Comment: I also believe that the issue comes from the part where the JWT is generated (which is Keycloak)
But as i mentioned above, we've set up Keycloak to use RS256 (i might, say we forced it to use RS256). I have added out keycloak settings in the post...